# Selenium C# Tables - reading each values and adding them and Returning as List<string>

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I can able to read the table values BUT Im unable to add the values inside foreach loop and returning them as `List<string>`.

Please share your approach and Will be great helpful

```
IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='table']"));
IList<IWebElement> tableRow = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
IList<IWebElement> rowTD;

foreach (IWebElement row in tableRow)
{
    rowTD = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
    //add the values in list?? 
}

return list
```

After this how can I add the td text values into an `List<string>`? I want this function to return the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are trying to return all of the table data elements as a list of strings.
If you want to stick with a similar approach of only getting the text of the td elements, then I would do something like this:

```
IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='table']"));
IList<IWebElement> tableDataElements = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

var reults = new List<string>();

foreach (IWebElement tableDataElement in tableDataElements)
{
    var tableData = tableDataElement.Text;
    reults.add(tableData);
}

return reults;
```

Comment: Highly Appreciate your timely help and approach - Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [Michiel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54557434/1633949) with LINQ to do this even more concisely--without a foreach loop at all:

First, add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then, you can replace your entire code block with:

```
return driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='table']"))
          .FindElements(By.TagName("td"))
          .Select(e => e.Text)
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Great Thanks for providing the more effective way. which variable will hold the string list values ? how to return a value from LINQ?

Comment: @stan In this case, no variable is made to hold them, they are returned as a list. if you wanted to put the list into a variable, it would chanve to `var result = ` at the very beginning rather than `return`

Comment: You question just said "I want this function to return the list."  This creates the list and returns it all in the same statement, with no intermediate List variable needed.   if you need the intermediate variable, you can easily do what @MichielBugher suggests in the preceding comment  (save the output from .ToList() in a variable, and then return the variable.)